# PHP code in Drupal8 template

Tags: twig, drupal-8

How to use normal PHP code in Drupal 8 twig template?

```
require_once(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include.php'));
```

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: You are ruining the whole point of a template language.

Thing like that are not done even in D7 which uses PHP as template language.

If you need to include another script in your template then you must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use PHP in a Twig template.

I don't know what you're exactly trying to accomplish but there are many hooks and spots in the render pipeline of Drupal where you can put your PHP logic, so no need to do this "hacky" stuff. Maybe we can give you a hint where to look, if you tell us what your include.php file is supposed to do.

Comment: I do have a similar issue, where I need to add a function in node.html.twig.
I need to add a disqus function for setting the identifier based on a field in the node for the widget to load. But am not sure how I will add that to the template.

this.page.identifier = '<? php echo $my_identifier; ?>';

This is the one I need to add.

Answer (score 1):

you can attach variable to twig templates using hooks to your templates.

There is no option to use php in twig.